# Adding class to item in array based on it's value

Tags: css, arrays, ruby-on-rails, ruby, combinations

so I simply want to change the colour of the text of a list of arrays based on the word that's in the string.

Here's my array of combinations currently being outputted in the view with `<%= @output %>`:

```
[{"Mer lec sai ham"=>{:price=>13.1, :points=>53.4}}, {"Mer rus sai ham"=>{:price=>12.1, :points=>32.2}}, {"Fer rus sai ham"=>{:price=>13.1, :points=>31.4}}, {"Mcl rus sai ham"=>{:price=>13.5, :points=>14.9}}]
```

CSS:

```
 span.mer{color:red;}
 span.lec{color:green;}
```

And then I am just calling it in my view using  `<%= @combo %>`

The ouput should be the list of combinations but this time just the words are coloured correctly. This is currently just showing nothing, it's not throwing errors though.

**EDIT**
Added my full controller code in case it's needed:

```
# DEFINE VARIABLE AND TARGET
     teams = team_price.keys
     drivers = driver_price.keys
     target = 13.5

    # CREATE METHOD TO SUM BOTH PRICES AND POINTS FOR GIVEN COMBINATION
    def add_up(combo, ht, hd)
      t, d = combo
      ht[t] + hd.values_at(*d).sum
    end

    # METHOD TO DOUBLE HIGHEST DRIVER POINTS
    def add_dbl(combo, team_points, driver_points)
      t, ds = combo
      dmax = ds.max_by { |d| driver_points[d] }
      driver_points[dmax] + add_up(combo, team_points, driver_points)
    end

    # ALL POSSIBLE COMBINATIONS OF TEAM AND DRIVERS
    all_driver_combos = drivers.combination(3).to_a
    all_combos = teams.product(all_driver_combos)

    # SHOW ALL COMBOS WHERE SUM DOES NOT EXCEED TARGET
    valid_combos = all_combos.select do |c|
      add_up(c, team_price, driver_price) <= target
    end

    # SORT VALID COMBOS BY SUM OF POINTS FOR EACH ELEMENT
    ordered = valid_combos.sort_by do |c|
      -add_dbl(c, team_points, driver_points)
    end

    # SORT DRIVERS BY HIGHEST POINTS
    ordered.each do |_t,ds|
      ds.sort_by! { |d| -driver_points[d] }
    end

    # OUTPUT
    output = ordered.map do |c|
      { c.join(" ")=>{ price: add_up(c, team_price, driver_price),
             points: add_dbl(c, team_points, driver_points).round(2)} }
    end

    # CONVERT OUTPUT TO HASH
    @output = output.reduce Hash.new, :merge
```

**Table Edit**
I would now like to place this combination output in a table as follows (whilst keeping the colour coding solution):

| Team | Double | Drivers | Price | Points |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Mer | lec | sai ham | 13.1 | 53.4 |
| Mer | rus | sai ham | 12.1 | 32.2 |
| Fer | rus | sai ham | 13.1 | 31.4 |

In my view, I now have:

```
<table class="table table-condensed">
   <thead>
      <tr>
      <th>Combo</th>
      <th>Price</th>
      <th>Points</th>
      </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
      <% @output.each do |key,value| %>
         <tr>
         <td><%= raw(key.gsub(/Mer/, '<span class="mer">Mer</span>')) %></td>
         <td><%= value[:price] %></td>
         <td><%= value[:points] %></td>
         </tr>
      <% end %>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

Which is currently outputting:

```
Combo           Price   Points
Mer lec sai ham 13.1    53.4
Mer rus sai ham 12.1    32.2
Fer rus sai ham 13.1    31.4
Mcl rus sai ham 13.5    14.9
```

However as shown in the table example above I would like it so that 'Combo' is split up into the correct columns. Like so:

Before:
Mer lec sai ham | 13.1 | 53.4

After:
Mer | lec | sai ham | 13.1 | 53.4

Price and points work fine, but it's just a case of splitting up the combo. Looking at the table I would like to create, the 'team' (e.g Mer, fer) is always going to be the first value in the array. 'Double' is always the second value in the array (lec in the above case) and then 'Driver' is just the remaining values (sai ham in the above case). Because the array is ordered in this way is there a way to pull each out using something like: `.key[1]` or somehow assign each key a new name? Thanks for the help!

Comment: Please show us the full controller method, the view.
Also: not sure how your comparison logic works,. Are you checking if the word (Mer, lec) is contained? Because there is no "lec" without "Mer" in your sample data...

Comment: Thanks. Yeah I’d like to go through and see which words are contained and colour them. Lec is independent from Mer? So hoping to apply a different colour to lec then mer

Comment: `<%= @combo %>` does not display anything because `#each` returns `nil` so when you do `@combo = output.each do |p|`, the value of `@combo` is set to`nil`. Could you share an example of the `output` variable content please ?

Comment: Thanks @SébastienP. I've included my full controller code. Hopefully that helps? I've adjusted the code slightly from before, but In my view I am just calling `<%= @output %>` and `<%= @combo %>`. `<%= @output %>` is just the list of combinations. Aim is to show exactly `<%= @output %>` but now just with mer and lec coloured. Thanks for the help!

Comment: `Array#each` does not return `nil`

Comment: Indeed @Pascal, just tested it and you're right, it returns the array itself, confirmed by the documentation: https://apidock.com/ruby/Array/each

Comment: Based on the comments, I’m guessing my @output each_do line is completely the wrong way to go about this? I took that way of doing it from another thread I found?

Comment: You haven't posted any of your front end code. How are you using `@combo` in your view?

Comment: There isn't any - My front end view is literally just  `<%= @combo %>`  and  `<%= @output %>` at the moment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are using assignment (=) when you should be using comparison (==)?

```
@combo = @output.each do |p|
  if p = 'Mer'
    class_name = 'red'
  elsif p = 'lec'
    class_name = 'green'
  else
    class_name = 'black'
  end
end
```

Instead of

```
 @combo = @output.each do |p|
      if p == 'Mer'
        class_name = 'red'
      elsif p == 'lec'
        class_name = 'green'
      else
        class_name = 'black'
      end
    end
```

Also you are passing a hash as `p` and trying to compare it to a string. You don't need combo at all and should leave interface concerns out of your controller code. I would get rid of @combo. As far as stying things using CSS I try to keep it semantic. So I would name classes like:

```
span.mer{color:red;}
span.lec{color:green;}
```

And just leave black as the default.
**Edit**
Also if you can change your @output to just a simple hash of items with the string as the key and the hash of price and points as the value like this:

```
@output = {"Mer lec sai ham"=>{:price=>13.1, :points=>53.4}, "Mer rus sai ham"=>{:price=>12.1, :points=>32.2}, "Fer rus sai ham"=>{:price=>13.1, :points=>31.4}, "Mcl rus sai ham"=>{:price=>13.5, :points=>14.9}}
```

Possible view code(**Edited to address request for table**):

```
<table class="table table-condensed">
  <thead>
  <tr>
    <th>Team</th>
    <th>Double</th>
    <th>Drivers</th>
    <th>Price</th>
    <th>Points</th>
  </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  <% @output.each do |key,value| %>
    <tr>
      <% key = key.split(' ') %>
      <% key = "<td>#{key[0]}</td><td>#{key[1]}</td><td>#{key[2]} #{key[3]}</td>" %>
      <%= raw(key.gsub(/Mer/, '<span class="mer">Mer</span>')) %>
      <td><%= value[:price] %></td>
      <td><%= value[:points] %></td>
    </tr>
  <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

This will wrap any word with a `<span>` tag that applies the color to that word based on the css defs. If "Lec" could appear as "Lec" or "lec" I would change the regexp in gsub to be case insensitive.

Comment: Thanks - this hasn't worked just yet though. Isn't my combination (first block of code at the top) an array? Do you think converting it to a string will allow this to work?

Comment: See my edits. I don't think you should do that kind of stying in the controller. Just use sensible semantic names for your classes and apply them in the view. Your hash structure is a bit contorted when it comes to building the view. But the code above should work.

Comment: I'll edit my answer again with a better structure for your @output, which gives a simpler view code structure.

Comment: You can probably modify your controller code to output the simplified hash, but to get it for my example I just did: `@outpout = @output.reduce Hash.new, :merge`

Comment: Thank you! Works perfectly. You've actually half answered another question I've had, and wondered if you could shed any light on it. All those combinations I am planning on putting in a table. With headings: Team | Drivers | Price | Points. Your method of breaking my array up into a new hash with keys/values has allowed me to do so by wrapping each of your lines , `<%= raw(key.gsub(/Mer/, '<span class="mer">Mer</span>'))`, `<%= value[:price] %>` and `<%= value[:points] %>` in <td>. However, I would like to break up the Driver/team combo line, to be able to access each individually?

Comment: "I would like to break up the Driver/team combo line, to be able to access each individually" is very vague. Feel free to edit your question and add this to then. I need to know what you mean by access individually. Do you just want them split up visually with `<td>`?

Comment: I have updated all my code to now include your new code. And then under 'Table Edit' I've tried to explain what I mean. Basically somehow breaking the driver combo up into 3 parts. Thanks a lot for the help - really appreciate it!

Comment: Don't know why the # are causing weird markup in my answer but the updated table format will work. You can split a string on (' ') and it returns an array of words. Then you can access it as an array with foo[0] etc. Then just reassemble it with the <td> where you need them.

Comment: Thank you mate works great! At least I was on the right sort of lines just wasn't sure how to execute properly!

Answer (score 0):

Multiple problems:

- you are using *asignment* (=) instead of *comparison* (==)
- you are comparing (if you change it) a Hash to a string, which will never be true
- you are assigning a local variable (`class_name`) which does not have an effect on the output
- it seems you want to highlight each word with the color, not just the full sentence
- you have an array of hashes, where the key is a "sentence" (at least multiple words) which you want to highlight seperately and the value is a hash again.

Here is something to get you started (first step is to get code working, next step would be to clean it up. E.g. moving things to helpers or components or decorators).

```
def whatever_action_this_is
  @output_with_colors = @output.map do |item|
    item.transform_keys do |key|
      words = key.split(' ')
      highlighted = words.map do |word|
        content_tag(:span, word, class: css_class(word))
      end
      highlighted.join(' ')
    end
  end
end

private

def css_class(word)
  case word.downcase
  when 'mer' then 'red'
  when 'lec' then 'green'
  else 'black'
  end
end
```

And then in your view, assuming some ERB template

```
<ul>
<% @output_with_colors.each do |item|
  <% item.each do |key, value|
    <li>
      <%= key.html_safe %>
      <br/>
      <%= value %>
    </li>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
</ul>
```